# What are we supposed to do now about discipline issues?

Tags: discussion

Before the cluster-screw that was Stack Exchange wrongfully revoking Monica's mod status and the ensuing dozens of mods resigning/taking leaves of absence, we had some semblance of order and discipline on this site.

I've now noticed that some users have resumed undesirable behavior that was once addressed by mods but is now left unchecked.  I've been the target multiple times of harassment on Writing.SE specifically, and the mods always helped me out and addressed those who were disrespectful.

But since we have exactly *zero* mods at the moment, how do we as a community address this behavior if and when we see it happening again?

Comment: You might want to bring this up on [meta.se].

Comment: I assume you're already flagging.  I thought the CMs were supposed to be keeping an eye on things in the wake of the mod exodus.  If that's not happening, I second the suggestion to ask on main meta.

Comment: If you are come to [this chat room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and link to the comments, users there will probably help you flag them.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It seems they are, thankfully. [See this post](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/46139/23927) where the OP re-added an unnecessarily offensive edit that had been previously rolled back (by yourself, no less). The CMs have indeed re-removed the edit, locked the post, and suspended the user responsible.

Comment: @F1Krazy I'm shocked that the user has been suspended for a *year*.  Isn't that a little extreme?  (Note: I'm not defending this guy, he's repeatedly harassed me.)

Comment: @weakdna - The default suspension lengths recommended to moderators are 7 days, 30 days, and 365 days, for first-time, second-time, and third-time offenses respectively. Where I live on the exchange, the mod team typically lowers that number substantially, particularly for second- and third-timers who regularly make good contributions. I'm guessing that this particular user had been suspended twice before, and whoever intervened just went with the default. Maybe this user picked the wrong week to go on a rampage?

Comment: I personally haven't seen any of this undesirable behavior you mention. However, this is because I usually only click on the questions which interest me. While I'm not a mod, I am more than able to edit with a vengeance if you can point me to some of these instances.

Comment: @F1Krazy That post also shows another thing that is wrong with SE lately: Bad posts by unreasonable people are still netting them a ton of reputation, because once they get to HOT bar, often because they are controversial, not good, they get upvotes from the wide community, but only a small fraction can downvote them.